# Calling a function after downloading CSV in react-csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am using `react-csv` to download a CSV file. It is working as needed.

However, I want to call another function AFTER the CSV file is downloaded. Is this possible?

This is how I have tried to do it so far:

```
{
    finalXerodata && 
    <CSVLink
        data={finalXerodata}
        onClick={() => { console.log("Clicked!"); //this doesnt work }}
        disabled={(finalXerodata.length < 1)}
        headers={xeroColumns}
        filename="data.csv"
        className="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"
        style={{marginLeft: '20px'}}>Download CSV               
    </CSVLink>
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

The official documentation says an onClick event is available but it doesnt seem to work in this case.

Thanks

Comment: My react is very stale, but think you might be able to do something with `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`. If you use redux or a similar state management system, they will also include other lifecycle hooks you can use. So this isn't something that the react-csv library seems to offer.

Answer (score 0):

`react-csv` uses the vanilla `<a>` tag to serve the download link. Once the download is started, it runs in the background, separate from the document. There is no way to detect when the download is complete.

The `onClick` prop on the `CSVLink` component will run before the download dialog window is opened. You could still use it to trigger events, but you cannot ensure the user successfully downloaded the file.

Clicking on a `CSVLink` component seems to hijack the console output of your browser for some reason. This behaviour may fool you into thinking the `onClick` prop wouldn't work if you're testing it with console logging.

You've two options on how to proceed:

### 1: Extend the CSVLink component

You can replace the `<a>` tag with a smarter download component that can keep track of the download. It seems you could achieve this by only replacing the `render` method https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv/blob/master/src/components/Link.js
. This approach may use up a lot of developer time.

### 2: Rely on user input

You can detect the start of the download with `onClick`. You can then infer that the download is complete (or at least the download dialog has been closed) when the user interacts with the application again.

What you should do depends on what you're trying to achieve and how much control you want to have over the user experience.